# Cron won't execute my maven command

Tags: maven, cron

So I have created a user named build on my machine (RHEL). This user is the one that can execute a python script I made for the backend of a web application. Maven is installed for this user.

The python script is calling an `.sh` script which contains a `mvn clean install` command.

When I'm executing my python script from command line, everything is working just fine, but now I tried to automate it using a crontab and the maven command won't execute (but the rest of the `.sh` script is working, as I'm echoing sentences before and after the command).

Here is the content of my `crontab -u build -e`:

```
*/5 * * * * cd /product/************/**********/src/ ; ./buildEngine.py
```

Looks like it behaves as if maven wasn't installed, is there something I'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the paths for everything?  Are you expecting it to execute within the context of /product/.../src/?  Perhaps something is no running in the correct directory.

Comment: ya it's running in the same directory as I do when i'm executing it in command line. And it has no problem finding the scripts, it just won't execute the maven command

Comment: perhaps you'd get better results on superuser.com or serverfault.com . That's where the UNIX gurus are.

Comment: allright, is there a way to just move it or do i have to repost a new question?

Comment: @Sean - a vote to close (and move) would expedite this process for the OP :)

Comment: Is mvn in the path? Have you configured a settings under that user ($HOME/.m2/settings.xml)? Furthermore why are you doing this? It looks like you trying to do a continous integration build (why not using Jenkins/Hudson for that purposes; much more simpler to configure etc.).

Comment: @Kevin I know, but I didn't do it because I think this is a corner case. It *is* programming-related, after all. But now that everybody is voting, so am I :-)

Comment: @khmarbaise yes mvn is in the path, and the settings are configured. We're planning on moving it to jenkins soon but we still have some things that we need that can't be executed with Jenkins.

Comment: What about JAVA_HOME for the user? May be M2_HOME as well? What can't be executed with Jenkins? Can you make a su -l build and do mvn clean package there without any problems? What about the checkout of sources?

Comment: both home are set, mvn clean package is working and there is no problem with the checkout. Once again everything is working just fine if I execute it from command line as build user. For Jenkins we're using it for all our other builds, there is just one or two operations on this script that we need to find a way to make it work on jenkins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the environment isn't being set up properly for your user when cron is running your .sh script. Try adding a `PATH=$PATH:<path to mvn>` at the start of the script to see if it can find Maven then. Also see the INVOCATION section of `man bash` for details on how a shell is initialized.

Comment: isn't cron using the same settings for the user build as when I'm logged in as build and running the script?

Comment: That's very unlikely. Check the bash man page that I mentioned to see all the different ways that a shell can be initted.